# How to create table for my perl output using perl cgi?

Tags: cgi

---

Here is my code and output i was unable to create the different row for my each line using perl?

Here is my code:

```
   use strict;
    use warnings;
    use CGI;
    open(my $file1,"as.txt");
    my $firstline=<$file1>;
    $firstline=~s/.*=//g;
    my @words=split /,/,$firstline;
    my $finalline=join("\n",@words);
    close $file1;
    print "Content-type:text/html\n\n"
    print<<"EOF";
    <html><body>
    <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
    <th>UserName</th>
    <th>Access</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>$finalline</td>
    <td>
    <input type="checkbox" value="check2" mulitple checked>Read
    <input type="checkbox" value="check2" mulitple>Write
    <input type="checkbox" value="check2" mulitple>Owner
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table></body></html>
    EOF
```

MY OUTPUT FOR PERL (I.E $finalline)
 sankar
 morien3

i got the following table as my output in table format:

```
UserName    Access
sankar morien3 Read Write Owner
```

Expected output:

```
UserName    Access
sankar  Read Write Owner
morien3 Read Write Owner
```

Input file:(i.e as.txt)

```
cskTeam = sankar, mobrien3
[csk:/]

* = r
@cskTeam = rw
```

Comment: Please add your input file.

Comment: added my input file@mkHun

Comment: Answer added for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must know about how HTML layout will work.

Even your code won't give your expected result in terminal.

In html `\n` not make sense, `<br>` it is for new line in html. But this logic also won't work in your code.

You are joining the array with `\n`, then printing the data it will execute the comment line by line what you have mentioned.

First you have printing the `$finalline` variable so it result is

```
sankar \n morien3
```

**\n will not consider in html. Storing in one cell as per `<td>`**

**Then you are creating the another cell which holds the permission detail.**

Finally your code should be as follows.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use CGI;

use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

print "Content-Type: text/html \n\n";


open my $file1,"<","as.txt";
my $firstline=<$file1>;
$firstline=~s/.*=//g;
my @words=split /,/,$firstline;
close $file1;


print<<"EOF";
<html><body>
<table style="width:50%; ">
<tr>
<th style="text-align:left">UserName</th>
<th style="text-align:left">Access</th>
</tr>
EOF
foreach (@words)
{
print <<EOF;
<tr>
<td>$_</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" value="check2" mulitple checked>Read
<input type="checkbox" value="check2" mulitple>Write
<input type="checkbox" value="check2" mulitple>Owner
</td>
</tr>
EOF
}
print <<EOF;
</table></body></html>
EOF
```

Comment: your script print the same line in two row .It wont print as like my expected  output@ mkhun

Comment: Now it executes fine.@ mkhun

Comment: @srvvani Please learn and code the Perl-cgi script like [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html) and also add [fataltobrowser](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI/Carp.html) also in your code.

Comment: Using EOF is also an  cgi method.Why we should prefer print for every line@mkHun