# how to print the output of a per CGI script for loop in table format using HTML tags

Tags: html, perl

The following is my loop(written as a part of perl-CGI script). I want it to print in table in my webpage using html table tags. How shall I do that?

```
for($ff=0;$ff<scalar @phi;$ff++)
{

    print $res[$ff],"---->";
    printf("%0.2f",$omg[$ff]);
   print "<br>";
   print "\n";


}
```

Comment: [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44039354/how-to-create-table-for-my-perl-output-using-perl-cgi/44062497#44062497)

Comment: @mkHun: That answer demonstrates putting raw HTML into the Perl program. Surely, we're not still recommending that approach?

Comment: Your question is very broad. You seem to have a list of value pairs, and you say you want to display that in a table. How do you want that to look? Should `$res[$ff]` be one column, and `$omg[$ff]` another column? Are there headings? Is there more data? Please [edit] your question and include more details, so we know what to help you with. Please do **not** expect us to just write this code for you.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend creating a data structure that contains the data you're interested in.

```
my @rows;
# Strange that you're getting the indexes from @phi
# and the data from two different arrays, @res and @omg
for (0 .. $#phi) {
  push @rows, {
    res => $res[$_],
    omg => sprintf('%0.2f', $omg[$_]),
  };
}
```

Then process that data using the [Template Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template).

```
use Template;

my $tt = Template->new;
$tt->process('page.tt', { rows => \%rows });
```

In `page.tt` you would have something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Data Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Data Page</h1>
    <table>
[% FOR row IN rows -%]
      <tr><td>[% rows.res %]</td><td>[% rows.omg %]</td></tr>
[% END -%]
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Separating the presentation like this makes it far easier to change the way that your data is presented. You could even give the template to a front-end designer to make it look better - and they wouldn't need to know Perl.